# Using UTF-8 chars with `write` message program

Tags: konsole, unicode

when I use the `write` program to send messages, how can I use UTF-8 chars?

I send:

```
write user2
Ehilà! Com'è?
```

But receiver gets:

```
Message from user1@samehost on pts/1 at 21:08 ...
EhilM-CM- ! Com'M-CM-(?
```

The machine is the same and `LANG` in konsole is already `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Whose Konsole?  Yours?  The other user's?  Both?

Answer (score 11):

It appears `write` is interpreting the high bit as ‘meta-’ (<kbd>Meta</kbd>+key or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key). A quick look at the source code (function `wr_fputs()` in `write.c`) confirms this: control characters are shown as `^X`, characters with the high bit set are shown as `M-X`. Locale settings, terminals and encodings have nothing to do with it, I'm afraid. `write` is just 7-bit.

Now, I'm a Unicode freak, but this makes a perverted sort of sense. `write` just opens the target TTY and writes to it (there's no magic involved). There's no easy way to get the character encoding understood by the process controlling the remote TTY. And even if there were, not all encodings are convertible to all other encodings. And without conversion, transmitting a message in KOI8-R to an ISO-8859-1 console would fail miserably. Since `write` takes the simplistic, 70s approach, this is what we get.

Comment: Wow.  Just wow.  So much for 8-bit clean.

Comment: I know. Though there are a few mitigating circumstances (I added them to the answer... too long for a comment)

Comment: (1) It might have been nice if you linked to the source code you found.   (2) Were there any comments in that code?  I suspect that this was done at least partly as a security measure, to prevent malicious users from sending escape sequences and other manipulative content to other users.

Comment: At least on Linux, the tty line discipline settings do have a `iutf8` setting. It needs to know if your terminal sends UTF-8, so that for instance, when you type é (2 bytes, one character) followed by backspace, it knows you have deleted two bytes and only needs to send backspace space backspace for the terminal to erase on its screen. So `write` could tell which terminals are likely working in UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using FIFO pipe.

1. Create the FIFO pipe:

   ```
   mkfifo /tmp/fifo
   ```
2. Let another user listen on the other end.
   If we are awaiting multiple messages on this pipe, for convenience, we can put the read pipe command into a `for` loop, so when the listener receives `EOF` of first message, bash will automatically connect to the pipe again. This loop execution could be interrupted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when needed:

   ```
   for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) do cat /tmp/fifo ; done
   ```
3. Then you can send any Unicode text messages, or redirect output of any command to this FIFO pipe, for example:

   ```
   ls -l /bin/ > /tmp/fifo
   ```

Comment: This does not actually *answer* the question.  It’s a workaround — a “pull”, whereas ``write`` is a  “push”.  It’s OK to post it as an answer, but you should identify it as a workaround.